# Do you need concentrated sulfuric acid to make Dische diphenylamine reagent and test for DNA?

Tags: organic-chemistry, concentration, dna-rna

I'd like to do a DNA quantification experiment for a college project. I don't want to use 16 M sulfuric acid. Is it possible to use more dilute acid and get a reasonably good result?